# Customizing AppDelegate, adding a ViewController property, then setting this property: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16574320

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, delegation

I am not sure if this is the best architecture or not, or if I am going to run into trouble with this, but I am fairly new at objective-c and iOS development, and this is my first attempt at using delegation, etc. in my own architecture.

Here is my AppDelegate interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "XMPPStream.h"
#import "XMPPController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *currentViewController;

//@property (strong, nonatomic) XMPPStream *xmppStream;
@property (strong, nonatomic) XMPPController *myXMPPController;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;


@end
```

As one can see, there is a UIViewController property.

In another class, I want to access and set this property.

Here is the interface of this class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XMPPStream.h"

@interface SignInViewController : UIViewController <XMPPStreamDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UserNameTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PassWordTextField;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) XMPPStream *myStream;
- (IBAction)SignInButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

and in method `SignInButtonPress`, I want to do exactly this (set the UIViewController property of the AppDelegate instance handling the app):

```
- (IBAction)SignInButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender {

    AppDelegate *myAppDel = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    myAppDel.currentViewController = self;
```

The app crashes on the second line of that method (`myAppDel.currentViewController = self;`), with the following being output to the console:

> 2014-12-13 16:55:23.744 myApp1919:60b] -[AppDelegate
>   setCurrentViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1653c010 2014-12-13 16:55:23.753 myApp[1919:60b] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[AppDelegate setCurrentViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x1653c010'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x305a6f83 0x3ad57ccf 0x305aa917 0x305a9203 0x304f8768 0x5fe97 0x32df9037 0x32df8fd7 0x32df8fb1
>   0x32de4717 0x32df8a2f 0x32df8701 0x32df36cb 0x32dc88cd 0x32dc6f77
>   0x3057220b 0x305716db 0x3056fecf 0x304daebf 0x304daca3 0x353e0663
>   0x32e2714d 0x7167d 0x3b264ab7) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

So, my question is, why is this not working? Am I simply missing something, like adding protocol compliance to one of this classes, or am I missing something else? Or is there something incredibly wrong with this kind of architecture to begin with?

Thanks!

best regards,

C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `self.window.rootViewController = <any viewcontroller reference>;`rather than window.currentViewController.

There is no such method named, `currentViewController` to set.

Comment: myAppDel.rootViewController does not resolve, there seems to be no such property. Furthermore, does adding the currentViewController to my appDelegate interface as a property not create a setter and a getter for this property? At least that is what I seem to remember, but maybe it's not quite true or it should work.

Comment: It turns out I just forgot to alloc and init the appDelegate UIViewController property. But since your answer seems to work as well, I will accept it as the correct answer for this question. Thanks! :)